# Delete in COBOL DB2 with fetch first 100 rows

Tags: db2, delete-row, cobol

Below is my query that am using in cobol db2 module

```
EXEC SQL
DELETE FROM AA_AA 
WHERE A=0
FETCH FIRST 30 ROWS ONLY
END-EXEC
```

I could see the below error while compiling

> INVALID KEYWORD 'FETCH' VALID SYMBOLS ARE: AND OR QUERYNO SKIP  WITH DELETE FROM AA_AA WHERE A=0 FETCH FIRST 30 ROWS ONLY

Comment: The Fetch is not valid in a Delete query. Plus you can't ask to delete any 30 rows, you must provide a condition that will discriminate those records from the ones you need to keep. Perhaps you could explain us what you intended to do in the first place. By the way, this is a DB2/SQL question and has almost nothing to do with cobol.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: 
DELETE FROM (SELECT * FROM AA_AA WHERE A = 0 FETCH FIRST 30 ROWS ONLY)